# Only apply validation if value exists?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have some validation rules:

```
return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required_without:email',
        'email' => 'required_without:phone|email',
    ];
```

I want to validate that if there is a phone, you don't need email, and if there is an email, you don't need a phone.

I've managed that with the above but when you enter a phone number and leave email blank (this should be allowed) I get the validation error that the email is not formatted as an email address.

How can I allow phone or email and if email it needs to be email formatted?

Comment: `nullable` rule?

Comment: Yes - nullable does it - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
if($request->input("phone")){
     $data["phone"] = $request->input("phone");
     $validate = '';
}elseif($request->input("email")){
     $data["email"] = $request->input("email");
     $validate = 'email';
}

return 
Validator::make($data, [
                         'name' => 'required',
                         key($data) => array('required',$validate)
                       ],
```